# Can water in a small container increase the humidity of the surrounding area?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, humidity

I have been instructed to keep a liquid drug in a cool and dry place (away from humidity), at temperature not exceeding $25^\circ$ C, but also to avoid freezing it, as it may crystallize. On a very hot summer day, when maximum temperature is exceeding $40^\circ-45^\circ$ C, can I keep the drug bottle inside an open-lid bowl with water inside it, to keep it cool? Or will the drug catch humidity while doing so?

Comment: As long as it is closed airtight it will be ok, no humidity can come in. The instructions for humidity are for an opened bottle. May be the container cannot be made air tight, and in this case you should put it inside an airtight container.

Comment: This is something you should discuss with the pharmacist or doctor.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been instructed to keep the drug away from humidity, and if your sample is open to air, it will absorb moisture. Also, if the ambient temperature is 40-45°C, I doubt that an open pool of water would keep the temperature below 25°C, as you need it to.